# Laravel Blade view not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3.28 version. I have created main view(main.blade.php) and trying to extract the details from different child views(navbar.blade.php) which is in view/pages directory but its not working.

Route file in project/routes/web.php

```
            Route::get('/', function () {
                return view('main');
            });
```

Main view in resources/views/main.blade.php(this file will receive the data from navbar.blade.php)

```
                        <div id="column">Test1</div>
                        <div id="container">
                            @yield('content')<!--This will get the content from navbar.blade.php-->
                        </div>
```

child view in resources/views/pages/navbar.blade.php

```
            @extends('main')
            @section('content')
                    <div id="row">
                       Test2
                     </div>
            @endsection
```

I am able to see output as Test1 but not Test2. Why it this happening?

Answer (score 1):

To see navbar content you should return `navbar` view:

```
Route::get('navbar', function () {
    return view('navbar');
});
```

But if you're planning to include navbar in many views, you should use `@include()` instead of using `section()`, `extends()` and `yield()`:

```
@include(`navbar`)
```

Comment: I kept the same code for route, rremoved yield,section and extends and tried @include('pages.navbar'). It works

Answer (score 1):

For seeing the output Test2 you have to return `navbar` view

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('navbar');
    });
```

`@yield` is a place when you will extends `main view` then you can put something inside this content.

I am explaining below by an example using your view file

you can simply put this in navbar.blade.php. it doesn't needs to be extended.

```
 <div id="row">
     Test2
 </div>
```

In your main.blade.php you can put this

```
  <div id="column">Test1</div>
                    <div id="container">
                        @include('navbar')
                      @yield('content')  
  </div>
```

The suppose you have decided to create a third view which will extends main view with navbar view. suppose your created a view named home.blade.php and add this to your home.blade.php view

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
 Welcome Home !!!
@endsection
```

Then if you calls create your route like below

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

It will render like below

```
<div id="column">Test1</div>
                <div id="container">
                      <div id="row">
                        Test2
                      </div>
                 Welcome Home !!!  
               </div>
```

Hope this will clear your concept about view rendering

Comment: By default I am calling main.blade.php which will contain the common code and the navbar is dynamic content which will get added to main. is it not possible?

Comment: see and read my updated answer. it will clear your concept about extending view

Answer (score 1):

you should call view('navbar') instead of view('main') because navbar is a child of main view

if you call parent child content will not be seen there for call view('navbar')